# Debian backup files after chmod 770 in /etc

Tags: permissions, backup, ftp, chmod

I broke my debian permissions by doing: `chmod 770 /etc` as root.

I know its almost impossible to fix this without reinstalling but is it atleast possible to backup the files I created? I still have root access at the moment with putty.

I tried to copy files with sftp in filezilla what used to work fine before but broke after this command. Is there a way to solve the sftp permissions so I can backup some files I can't lose? Or isn't this possible anymore?

Whats the best way to still backup my files?

EDIT:

SSH is working again. When connecting to SSH I get like 20 messages with: `-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied`. I'm still unable to connect with SFTP at the moment after login into SFTP the server disconnects instantly.

Comment: If you did exactly `chmod 770 /etc` (non-recursive, and on the directory, not the files therein) you can fix it by running `chmod 755 /etc`.

Comment: To what do you want to backup your files? You can use scp, rsync to copy it over network to other linux machine.

Comment: @mrc02_kr I can only backup to a windows machine.

Comment: Download WinSCP program and download those files to your PC.

Comment: @StephenKitt I did some more commands allready trying to "fix" it. I'm just looking for a way to backup my files at the moment

Comment: @mrc02_kr I can't connect with WinSCP or SSH anymore I'm getting a network error (no error codes)

Comment: Have you tarred/zipped the files, already ? If not, do that first. Next, you claim you can only backup to a Windows system using scp/sftp, right ? you cannot attempt to mount a Windows share? 
Try `nc -l -p 1234 > file.tar.gz` on windows (using netcat, it must be installed) and `nc -w 3 windows_server_ip 1234 < file.tar.gz` on the linux server. You might need to open some ports, this will use port `1234`, you might want to use another port.

Comment: @thecarpy I can backup using anything as long as it goes over the internet. I have ssh access and can install anything on my windows machine. I didn't tar my files yet gonna do that first!

Comment: `tar cfz files.tar.gz /etc`. SInce this is going over the open internet, do `gpg -c files.tar.gz` and enter strong password prior to using netcat (`nc`)

Comment: @thecarpy I can't portforward my windows pc at the moment. Is it possible to get a FTP server working on my Debian machine? Something is still wrong with the permissions when trying to connect with FTP or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change permissions to /etc to 755. Then go to /etc/ssh folder and change permissions according to these below:

```
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root     242153 Mar 16  2016 moduli
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root       2208 Mar 16  2016 ssh_config
-rw-------.   1 root root       6702 Jun 28 16:36 sshd_config
-rw-------    1 root ssh_keys    227 Jun 28 16:36 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root root        162 Jun 28 16:36 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root ssh_keys    387 Jun 28 16:36 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root root         82 Jun 28 16:36 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root ssh_keys   1679 Jun 28 16:36 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root root        382 Jun 28 16:36 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Then restart ssh service and check if it's working.

**EDIT:**
You can also try:

```
cd /etc
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

This will allow you to access files in /etc via browser on port 8080

Comment: I can login to my ssh now but still a connect to winscp doesn't seem to work. I still get no error codes. After filling in my username/password winscp just closes the connection.

Comment: Default file protocol is SFTP. Try to change it to SCP

Comment: How can I change my SFTP protocol to SCP?

Comment: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols

Comment: @Stefan can you try solution with Python ?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for backed up 1gb of files in 2 min! Thanks alot!

Comment: +1 for mentioning SimpleHTTPServer